# ChatUML Homepage --> "Menu" : Navigate to Menu syntax error

Tags: openai-api, diagram

```
title Browsing Menu Activity Diagram

[*] --> Homepage
Homepage --> "Menu" : Navigate to Menu
"Menu" --> "Browse Categories" : Click on Menu
"Browse Categories" --> "View Items" : Select Category
"View Items" --> "View Item Details" : Click on Item
"View Item Details" --> "Add to Cart" : Add Item to Cart
"Add to Cart" --> "Shopping Cart" : Proceed to Cart
"Shopping Cart" --> [*] : Return to Homepage
```

5th line in syntax error

when i use this type of statement then throw syntax error